# Simulating partial credit model polytomous IRT data using psych package for R

Tags: r, simulation, psychometrics, item-response-theory

I see that the "psych" package for R includes many simulation options. I see in the help file that the user can specify the IRT model for the simulation, but I am not sure how to distinguish among the models in the code.

If, for example, I want to specify the Rasch rating scale model (polytomous), I think I could simply set the slopes/item discriminations to be equal in the sim.poly() function. But how would I distinguish this from the partial credit model? Is there a way to specify generating threshold values for each item?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, psych simulates data from the graded response model because it is more easily specified within the limited information factor analysis framework. You want a more IRT specialized package if you want to simulate data for this model.

Comment: @ philchalmers Thanks! Do you know of a package that does PCM simulation? I'm not having much luck in my search.

Comment: mirt will with the simdata() function

Comment: @philchalmers Thanks! I'm looking at that package, and I see the PCM option in simdata(). Is the "d" argument (intercepts) where the thresholds are specified for this model?

Comment: Correct, the package uses the slope intercept format